# Convert MySQL While Loop from PHP to NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js

I'm converting my PHP/MySQL code to NodeJS. But I've gotten stuck on the While loop and not sure where to return the data. Here's the code;

```js
var mysql = require("mysql");
var express = require("express");
var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
var config = require("../config");
var connection = require("../database");

var getFCM = function (req, res) {
    const bodyuserid = req.body.id;

    var query = "SELECT ?? FROM ?? WHERE userid = ? ";
    var table = ["audioid", "subscribe", bodyuserid];
    query = mysql.format(query, table);

    connection.query(query, function (err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ Error: true, Message: "Error executing MySQL query" });
        } else {
            var n = 0;
            var thislength = rows.length;
            var newaudioid = rows[n].audioid;

            var query = `SELECT ap.audioid, ap.title, us.name FROM audioposts ap INNER JOIN audioposts a2 ON a2.audioid = ap.opid INNER JOIN accounts us ON us.id = a2.userid WHERE ap.opid = ? AND ap.opid <> 0`;
            var table = [newaudioid];
            query = mysql.format(query, table);

            while (n < thislength) {
                connection.query(query, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        res.json({ Error: true, Message: "Error executing MySQL query" });
                    } else {
                        console.log(data);
                        res.json(data);
                    }
                });
                n++;
            }
        }
    });
};
module.exports = getFCM;
```

So the first query selects all `audioid`s  from the `subscribe` table of a certain `userid`.

The next query takes the resulting audioid's from the first query and fetches all posts   from the audiopost table where each resulting audioid's is the original post id (opid).

The code is nearly working but does not return the required title, name and audioid for each result of the second query. Instead it only returns one result. IE;

```json
[
  {
    "audioid": 147,
    "title": "Goat Heaven",
    "name": "Josie Jones"
  }
]
```

How can I get the loop to return the correct JSON data?

Here are the error messages in the NodeJS console;

```
[
  RowDataPacket {
    audioid: 147,
    title: 'Goat Heaven',
    name: 'Josie Jones'
  }
]
/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/Node-MySQL-JWT-Signup-Login-API/node_modules/mysql/li                                             b/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the cli                                             ent
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/Node-MySQL-JWT-Signup-L                                             ogin-API/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/Node-MySQL-JWT-Signup-Log                                             in-API/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/Node-MySQL-JWT-Signup-Log                                             in-API/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/Node-MySQL-JWT-Signup-Login                                             -API/middleware/getFCM.js:34:10)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/Node-MySQL-JWT-Signup-Login                                             -API/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/Node-MySQL-JWT-Signup-Login-A                                             PI/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/Node-MySQL-JWT-Signup-Logi                                             n-API/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/Node-MySQL-JWT                                             -Signup-Login-API/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:149:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/Node-MySQL-JWT-Signup-Login-A                                             PI/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:133:8) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Dropping into a loop like this making a ton of individual calls to the database from client code is guaranteed to kill performance. It’s that much worse off this is a web app, which it obviously is.

Comment: What would you suggest instead?

Comment: Well, if possible I would suggest running multiple queries simultaneously. MySQL has syntax that makes this pretty easy for operations like inserts. For selects, you just separate your statements with semicolons and you'll receive multiple result sets. Of course, if you just substitute selection criteria into SQL strings there's a risk from SQL injection attacks. There are ways to do it with prepared statements, but I haven't actually done that from node.js so I'm not 100% certain of the practicality. The general principle is that there is significant overhead every time you make a call...

Comment: ...to the database. In many cases, the overhead of the call can be greater than the overhead of executing the queries themselves. So if you drop into a loop and do that over and over, you are adding tons of performance-robbing overhead. It's better to aggregate the queries on the client side and send them as one batch. However; I'm also practical. If this is a few queries, not thousands, I wouldn't worry too much. This kind of looping is not uncommon, because it's the easiest thing to do. The fundamental issue you have here is that you can only call res.json() once per HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

You should to store results from MySQL into array and return all data after loop:

```
var getFCM = function (req, res) {
    const bodyuserid = req.body.id;

    var query = "SELECT ?? FROM ?? WHERE userid = ? ";
    var table = ["audioid", "subscribe", bodyuserid];
    query = mysql.format(query, table);

    connection.query(query, function (err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ Error: true, Message: "Error executing MySQL query" });
        } else {
            var n = 0;
            var thislength = rows.length;
            var newaudioid = rows[n].audioid;

            var query = `SELECT ap.audioid, ap.title, us.name FROM audioposts ap INNER JOIN audioposts a2 ON a2.audioid = ap.opid INNER JOIN accounts us ON us.id = a2.userid WHERE ap.opid = ? AND ap.opid <> 0`;
            var table = [newaudioid];
            query = mysql.format(query, table);
           
            var result = []; // init result array

            while (n < thislength) {
                connection.query(query, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        res.json({ Error: true, Message: "Error executing MySQL query" });
                    } else {
                        console.log(data);

                        result.push(data); // push data
                    }
                });
                n++;
            }
            res.json(result); // response fetched data
        }
    });
};
module.exports = getFCM;
```

Comment: I got this error with that code; ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at Query.<anonymous> (/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/Node-MySQL-JWT-Signup-Login-API/middleware/getFCM.js:40:22) . 40:22 is res.json(data);

Comment: I also tried this - res.json(result);  But only got this  [] empty Json back

Comment: That nearly worked but I'm getting an empty [] as the res.json(result);

Comment: Try to change `let result = [];` to `var result = [];`

Comment: I got a strange error with var result = []. Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
So I moved the location to just above var query and table. This stopped the error but again results were []

Answer (score 1):

Here it seems `while` loop tries to send response twice which is not possible, either you need to store your query data to another variable and once all processing done then send `res.json();`

Below is the straightforward snippet where its throwing the exception.

```
app.post('/api', async (req, res) => {
    let n=0
    while(n<2){
        res.json({msg:"Recevied"})
        n++
    }

});
```

It can be fixed with below snippet:

```
app.post('/api', async (req, res) => {
    let n = 0
    while (n < 2) {
        n++
    }
    res.json({ msg: "Recevied" + n })

});
```

Answer (score 1):

`res.json()` can only be called once per request because it sends all of the headers and data all-at-once, without buffering. Calling it a second time generates an exception. You're making a call to `res.json()` within a while loop, so it executes successfully the first time, then throws an exception the second time.

You could combine multiple sql statements and send them all to MySQL in one call. I prefer this approach because it is more performant. The most serious problem you will create if you're not cognizant and don't take steps to prevent it is that this can open you up to SQL injection attacks. You can do this with prepared statements (my *real* preference), but it takes a little more work and not all database clients are equally capable in that regard.

However; since it is so common to loop and make a call to MySQL each time through the loop--it is the easiest code to write in cases like this--your quickest fix to prevent throwing an exception here is going to be to append your JSON results to an array, then serialize the entire array in one call to `res.json(result)` at the end of your procedure.

If performance is a problem after the code is functionally correct, then look into solutions to send all of your queries as a batch.

The general principle I'm talking about is that there is significant communication overhead every time you make a round trip call to the database. The round-trip communication overhead can be more significant than the execution of the query itself. This is true of every database server, and MySQL is no different. In fact it is not only true of calls to databases, but even of calls into filesystems. Have you ever noticed how if you copy 1,000 small files it takes longer than copying one large file that is the same size or larger than the sum of the small files? All of that lost performance is going into opening and closing file handles and moving data in small chunks that don't fully utilize the IO subsystem. Additionally, not only is there significant per-call overhead, but you are holding a scarce/expensive database connection open the entire time the loop is running. This prevents any other HTTP requests from being able to utilize that connection. The loop is going to run longer than it would optimally, because you are waiting for the database to respond to every individual call. If you're doing four or five calls it won't be much of an issue. If you're doing thousands it will become a very big issue.

Comment: I looked into combining multiple mysql statements but I need the results of the first query in order to form the second query. Can you suggest an approach?

Comment: Huh, what is the relationship between the records? Are you sure they can’t all be retrieved with a single sql statement using an appropriate join condition? I once dissected a huge PL/SQL (Oracle) stored procedure that had two nested cursors being traversed in loops doing individual lookups in the inner loop based on the values retrieved from the cursor in the outer loop. It operated over millions of rows and took (I’m a little fuzzy, it was a long time ago) at least an hour and a half to run.

Comment: The report that used it could never be run during business hours. I actually used three colors of highlighters to mark up a printout of the stored procedure that went on for something like 12 pages. Once I was certain I understood what it was doing and that I wasn’t missing anything, I was able to replace it with one modestly complex sql query with a few table joins, tweaked the indexes, and it ran in under two seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use ORMs like `sequelize`(https://sequelize.org/) or `knex`(https://knexjs.org & https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/) rather than custom SQL query which leads to SQL injection.

Of course, there is a bit learning curve, but that's how you become a good programmer.

Comment: My understanding is that sequelize isn't good for complex queries?

Comment: It also supports raw queries if you want to use at particular cases

Comment: There's nothing like invoking all of the overhead of an ORM on a website to kill performance.  ;-)